# Getting the option value without using submit button

Tags: php, html

Good day. Im trying to have some functionality on my project, but im stuck with this.

**I want to display my database depending on what the user select**

Here is my html code:

```
        <table>
        <tr><td>Select Request Status:</td>
        <td><select class="form-control" name="status" style="width:200px;">
        <option value="1">Pending Request</option>
        <option value ="2">Requests On-Process</option>
        <option value="3">Unassigned Requests</option>
        <option>All Requests</option>
        </select></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

And here is my php code:

```
     if ($status = $_SESSION['status'] == 'Pending Request')
{
    $query = "select * from tblrequest where status='Pending Request'";
        $request = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());?>
        <table class="table">
        <tr>
                <th>Request ID</th>
                <th>Requestor</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Assigned to</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th>Created Time</th>
                </tr>
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($request)){
        ?>
        <tbody class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['RequestNumber']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['Requestor']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['Department']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:50px;"><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['AssignedTo']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['DateRequested']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['TimeRequested']; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<?php
}

}?>
```

Im a newbie to php so please help me.

Comment: You mean like.. `$_POST['status']`?

Comment: I tried to pass value of my select into php like that but it's not working :(

Comment: What isn't working? I don't see any code related to the option value in your PHP

Comment: you need to pass it using ajax.

Comment: How can i do that Maz?

Comment: RUJordan, i just forgot to include $status = $_POST['status']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

HTML:

```
       <form method="post">
            <table>
            <tr><td>Select Request Status:</td>
            <td>
              <?php $Statuses = array("0"=>"All Requests", "1"=>"Pending Request", "2"=>"Requests On-Process", "3"=>"Unassigned Requests" );?>

             <select class="form-control" name="status" style="width:200px;" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                <?php foreach($Statuses as $key=>$status):?>
                     <?php 

                     $selected ="";
                      $statusPost = $_POST['status'];
                      if($key == $statusPost): $selected =" selected"; endif;
                     ?>                    
                  <option value="<?php echo $key;?>" <?php echo $selected;?>><?php echo $status;?></option>
                <?php endforeach;?>

            </select></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
  if (isset($_POST['status'])){       
       $status= $_POST['status'];
       $Where ='';
          if($status!='0'){         
             $Where =" where status='".$Statuses[$status]."' ;           
          }
    }
       $query = "select * from tblrequest  $Where";
       $request = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());?> 
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
                <th>Request ID</th>
                <th>Requestor</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Assigned to</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th>Created Time</th>
                </tr>
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($request)){
        ?>
        <tbody class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['RequestNumber']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['Requestor']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['Department']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:50px;"><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['AssignedTo']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['DateRequested']; ?></td>
    <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $row['TimeRequested']; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<?php
}
   ?>
```

Comment: The table header appears and when im trying to select other option it keeps on selecting 'Pending Request'..

Comment: Sorry but it displays nothing.. Ive heard about ajax but i have no any idea how to use it

Comment: It your table status field column, how you have stored the status values?

Comment: It displays the table headers.

Comment: What do you mean by "how you have stored the status values"?

Comment: It displays the table header so i think the problem is this line <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($request)){
   ?>

Comment: Meant, `where status` column ? i.e you have stored the status column values in your table as `Pending Request/Requests On-Process/Unassigned Requests`

Comment: it is only problem query to fetch the result, do one thing just remove `where status='".$_POST['status']."'` from your select query and run

Comment: It displays the whole request but the other option is not displaying.

Comment: I used the update one and when i select "All users" it give me the whole data, but when i choose other option, it gives me only the header.

Comment: Reason is status columns, now I have updated my answer pls check. Make sure `$Statuses` array should be of the submit action coding

Comment: DUDE IT'S WORKING NOW! THANK YOU SO MUCH! You're so kind. Thank you for being so patient with me.

Comment: Hey 1 question, how can i select an specific option for what i want to display first?

Comment: You can the index of the array as per the priority you want and change the code accordingly

Comment: Can i have some example pls?

Comment: `<?php $Statuses = array("3"=>"All Requests", "0"=>"Pending Request", "1"=>"Requests On-Process", "2"=>"Unassigned Requests" );?>`

Comment: I see.. Why on first load the it displays nothing until selecting one?

Comment: As I said earlier you need to change the if condition according to the index key value

Comment: Updated my answer, please use it

Comment: I mean is everytime I refresh the page, "All Requests" is selected but displays nothing until I select another one.

Answer (score 1):

put select dropdown in a form with id,action,method etc.
give id to a select element(say "mySelect")

Now, in jquery,

```
$("#mySelect").on("change",function(){
if($("#mySelect").val() != ""))
{
   $("#form1").submit();
}
})
```

Comment: Im sorry but im new to this, can you give me a sample?